# How can I run Interaction Shell in .Net Core 3.1 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2019, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to run Shell commands to enable or disable firewall permissions upon connecting or disconnecting vpn and I have used **using microsoft.visualbasic** for that which work fine in Visual studio 2015 but now I am doing same thing in Visual Studio 2019 .Net Core and when I use the **microsoft.visualbasic** it shows error in Shell method as

> CS0117 'Interaction' does not contain a definition for 'Shell'

This is the code what I am trying to run

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net.NetworkInformation;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Collections;
using CasVPN.Model;
namespace CasVPN.Classes
{
class Global
{
public static void Disable_Network()
    {
        string value = "netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name = Block All Traffic dir =in action = allow port enable = yes remoteip = 5, 46, 48 - 1722, 1724 - 65535,LocalSubnet profile = public";
        Interaction.Shell("cmd.exe /c" + value);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: 1. You don't need an instance of `cmd.exe` to run `netsh.exe` 2. you'll need to use [`System.Diagnostics.Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process?view=netcore-3.1).

Comment: Why are you using `Interaction.Shell` in the first place? Just use `Process.Start(value);` Or `Process.Start("netsh","advfirewall firewall ...")`.

Comment: And everyone is just ignoring the fact of global vars, sigh. BTW when you use Process.Start(); and it doesn't work set `UseShellExecute = true;`.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.shell?view=netframework-4.8&viewFallbackFrom=netcore-3.1), Interaction.Shell is only available in .NET Framework and is not part of .NET Core.

You'll need to change your application to target .NET Framework or use an alternative method of running the command such as [Process.Start](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.start?view=netcore-3.1).